# Can't swipe on ViewPager2 only on one direction

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I try  to enable swipe in ViewPager2 only in ONE direction (to right). I has 5 pages.

I try this in my activity:

```
viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object :
            ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                super.onPageSelected(position)
                if (currentPage == position) {
                    dataBinding.viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false)
                }
                if (currentPage < position) { // swipe left
                    dataBinding.viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(true)
                } else if (currentPage > position) { // swipe right
                    dataBinding.viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false)
                }
                currentPage = position; 
            }
        })
```

but it not help. It's disable both directions.

Comment: have you found any proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var previousPage: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewpager.adapter = MyAdapter(this)
        viewpager.orientation = ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL

        // try this to disable swiping in previous page
        viewpager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels)
                if (position < previousPage) {
                    viewpager.setCurrentItem(previousPage, true)
                } else {
                    previousPage = position
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```